# String returned from PHP script into java program not working correctly

Tags: java, php, email

I am using a PHP script to access my database through my java program. PHP script sends and email and prints sent if the script was run successfully and the email was sent. The java program uses :

```
InputStream in = null;
            try {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
                in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                String inn = in.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }   

            String result = null;
            String sent = "sent";
            try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in,"iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    sb.append(line);
                in.close();
                result = sb.toString();
```

in order to get whats printed from the PHP script. Using Log i know that "sent" is being returned and the variable 'result' has the value "sent" when the PHP script successfully runs.
Now in the java file i am trying to do the following:

```
Log.e("result",result); <-- returns sent 

            if(result.equals("sent"))
            {                   
                ... do something
            }
```

I have tried a few different ways but no matter which way i try to compare 'result' to 'sent' it always fails.
If anyone has an idea of why this is happening I'd greatly appreciate any advice. Im sure its silly but i assume it has to do with PHP not returning exactly what i think it is, even tho Log shows that it is.

Comment: Are you sure that the value of result is `"sent"`?

Comment: Have you printed out the actual value of the `result` attribute or are you just guessing?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Also, you should _always_ output some kind of message in the catch block of a try-catch. Empty catch blocks lead to headaches later on.

Comment: @Hunter + Andrew - using Log.e("result", result) returns "sent" (no quotes) into the Log, so thats why im pretty sure its set to sent.
Thats all i have on declaring a setting result also, Andrew. all that is not shown is the PHP which is just an if statement and a print statement, that print statement is what is taking in by the java file and eventually put into 'result'

Comment: @user1070764 The reason we ask is because in a log file `"sent"` and `"sent         "` usually look the same. Check the length property of both strings.

Comment: Yes thats what im hoping it is and am checking for hidden spaces and characters now, thansk for the quick responses

Comment: Got it, with just a simple length check and @AndrewThompson 's hidden character check below it shows php is returning sent with an extra space on the end. Fixing that fixed my problem. Thank you all very much for the fast responses and solution

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
result.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("sent")
```

You could also do:

```
Log.e("result",result);

System.out.println( "!" + result.toString() + "!" );

if(result.equals("sent"))
{                   
     System.out.println( "Success" );
}
```

Comment: System.out.println( "!" + result.toString() + "!" ); // BAM